# Set arabic page numbers in all pages except the front page of MastersDoctoralThesis

Tags: header-footer, templates, thesis

I am using the following package:

http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/

I am having trouble setting page numbers for the entire thesis.
I want to display arabic page numbers in all the document except page 1 (title page). The problem is that my current configuration does not display the numbers in the first pages of the thesis before chapter 1 and also in the first chapter page of all chapters.

From the file provided, here are the things I  have modified for my own needs:

in main.tex:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%twoside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, 
oneside, %uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
%singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or 
%onehalfspacing,
doublespacing,
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

in MastersDoctoralThesis.cls:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS AND FOOTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead{}% Outer header}
    \ofoot{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}

}
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
%\ofoot{}% Outer footer
```

Key lines I added for what I want to achieve with the footer are as follows:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\ofoot{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}
```

Hope you guys can help me make this work! Cheers.

Comment: Before doing anything like that, check with your supervisor if your changes are acceptable. Sometimes supervisors or thesis commitees get **very** fussy about such details. (And they have provided a class to be used...)

Comment: I have. No worries in that regard.

Comment: Please have a look at the licence of the template. If you change something you have to change the name of the class.

Comment: You might improve your changes to get an answer if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Where is the comment header gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\frontmatter` switches the page numbering to roman by default. If you don't need it, remove it. Furthermore, the page style of the first few pages is set to `plain`. If you don't need it, remove it. Page numbers will appear.

If you want page numbers at the bottom, you already (almost* found it, use `\usepackage{lastpage}
\ofoot*{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}` in *the preamble of your document*. Of course, there is still the page number in the header, which needs to go. Use `\ohead*{}` *in the preamble of the document*.

You can also checkout `\setchapterpagestyle{thesis}` or `\setchapterpagestyle{thesisSimple}`.

*Do Not make Changes to the Class File!*.

You can also have a look at https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/